# How to make arched cabinet door with bevels

Tags: bevel

I want to make arched cabinet door like this one: [image: The door I want to make]

I tried creating the inner arched part first and then using boolean on a plane but everything became a mess and bevel doesn't work.

Here is my .blend file: [image]

Comment: at first i recommend adding an edge here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGHF.png -> just select both vertices and press F, then try again ;)

Comment: you also have the problem, that you have missing faces:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzrVZ.jpg

Comment: i would recommend watching some very basic beginner tutorials about modelling. So that you are sure what a face, an edge and a vertex is and how you can connect and build them.

Comment: basically a bevel works only if the geometry "underneath" is clean and if there are missing faces, it won't work, like e.g. here : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhzG.png

Comment: I tried with filling the mising faces with F but it didn't help, still the bevel doesn't work on this side @Chris

Comment: then pls upload your updated blend file again, so we can check it out

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=L4ggRBN7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/L4ggRBN7/) Here it is with filled face

Comment: there are still faces missing....[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xXag.png

Comment: and here as well: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmHFR.png so still two faces missing. i would recommend using viewport shading solid and move the model a bit, so you can see missing faces easily. But honestly: i don't have the patience now to show you all missing faces, maybe someone else does. You should watch beginner modelling tutorials and practice more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it with with a *Boolean* modifier. I would recommend starting all over again and do it like this (all I'm doing is just eyeballing it since I have no measurements for the object, but you can enter values for the operations as well). Okay, this will be quite long but I'm trying not to skip any steps that might be unclear:

1. Create the basic cuboid you need for the door. Make sure you've applied the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale* if you adjusted the scale in *Object Mode* instead of *Edit Mode*.

[image: apply scale]

2. Tab into *Edit Mode*. Select the top face, press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset it to the size of the outer border of the panel. Maybe scale or move on Y axis to get the correct offsets.

[image: inset]

3. Create a loop cut in the center of the long side of the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: loop cut]

4. Select the two edges on that side where you want to create arch. Right-click and choose *Subdivide* from the context menu.

[image: subdivide top edges]

5. For the next step it's easier to see in *Vertex Select* mode, so switch to it in the top bar menu or press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch. Select the new vertices in the middle of the subdivided edges. Scale them further apart with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd>, depending on how wide the arch should be.

[image: scale vertices apart]

6. Go back to *Edge Select* with <kbd>2</kbd> and select the two short edges towards the corners, then move them with <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> to make the "bottom" of the arch.

[image: move edges down]

7. Now press <kbd>3</kbd> for *Face Select* mode. Select the two inner faces and inset them again with <kbd>I</kbd> to the size of the inner panel.

[image: inset inner panel]

8. Switch back to *Edge Select* with <kbd>2</kbd>, select the center edge at the at the tip of the arch.

[image: select center edge]

9. Bevel this edge with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, scroll the mouse wheel to increase the number of segments - I would suggest an even number to kepp the center edge (I use 16 here) and left-click to confirm.

[image: bevel center edge]

10. The bevel will create unevenly spread segments if you are working with the default *Width Type* > *Offset*, so open the tool options in the bottom left of the editor window and switch it to *Percent*. At first the bevel seems to disappear since the amount jumps to 0.000%, but increasing this number will make it reappear again. I found a value of 90-92% quite fitting.

[image: switch to percent]

11. Select the top left faces and press <kbd>F</kbd> to merge them into one n-gon.

[image: merge faces]

12. Repeat this for the other "quadrants" of the split faces so that you have 4 new n-gons. Although everyone says n-gons should always be avoided, they make a much cleaner geometry and are unproblematic in this case.

[image: merged quadrants]

13. Now use *Face Select* again and select the face loop of the arch, an easy way is  to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Leftclick on the edge between two faces of the loop.

[image: select face loop]

14. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the faces downwards to the desired depth of the groove.

[image: extrude face loop]

15. With *Edge Select* you can now select the top rim edges of the inner panel and the outer door leaf. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+left-click on the edges to create all connected parts.

[image: select rim edges]

16. Bevel both edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This might look strange and incorrect because the *Bevel* tool uses the options from the last bevel. Just bevel a bit and left-click to confirm.

[image: bevel rim edges]

17. Open the tool options at the bottom left (if they are not already open). Switch *Width Type* back to *Offset* and make sure you enable *Clamp Overlap*. This way you can make the width very large but it will stop at the bottom edge with overlapping.

[image: change bevel options]

18. Now set the *Profile Type* at the bottom of the options menu to *Custom* instead of *Superellipse*. There you can set any profile you like (or some real profile which you want to recreate), maybe you have to increase the number of segments to get the best resolution for it.

[image: custom profile]

19. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* to make sure no double vertices remain from the clamped beveling.

[image: merge by distance]

20. Tab back into *Object Mode*, right-click on the object and choose *Shade Auto Smooth* to get a smooth looking surface.

[image: shade auto smooth]

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a plane, mirror it, draw the lines:

[image]

Then extrude twice to give it thickness:

[image]

Select the edges that are in the depth:

[image]

Then bevel with the *Custom* option, tweak the *Width* and the *Segments* values, create the custom profile:

[image]

Add some support edge loops in order to prepare your mesh to a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, of course you had to make a more beautiful custom profile... you swank :D Just kidding. Nice approach +1

Comment: Not so easy to use though  :p